# How to install the latest version of JavaScript Development Tools in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jsdt

On http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/ it says that the most recent version is 3.4. My Eclipse version is 4.2 Juno.

In *Help → Install new software...* when I search for it I only get the 1.4 JSDT. I've got the following software sites enabled:

```
Juno    http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno   Enabled
Mylyn for Eclipse Juno  http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/juno Enabled
The Eclipse Project Updates http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2 Enabled
```

So how do I install the 3.4 JSDT?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JSDT was only released under Web Tools Platform (WTP) version 3.4, this doesn't mean that the version of the JSDT itself has version 3.4 too.

You could probably update your WTP Version to 3.4. The repository could also be found under http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I just installed Luna and it's installed.  Here is what I found: from the [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT)

JSDT is included with WTP 3.0 and above.

To verify from Eclipse.  Go to the file menu, select Help - About Eclipse - Installation Details the Plugins Tab and it's listed there.